# keydown event on contenteditable span

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, here's the code:

```
 var max = 1;
    $('form').find('span').keydown(function(e){
        if ((e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 95 && e.which < 106)) {
            if ($(this).html() >= max) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).html($(this).html().substr(0,1));
               if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
                    $(this).parent().next().find('span:first-of-type').focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).next().focus();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.which != 8  && e.which != 9 && e.which != 46 && e.which != 37 &&    e.which != 38 && e.which != 39 && e.which != 40)

        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

First, I determine if the it's a number being put into, then I check if there's more than one digit being put in. If those conditions are met, I prevent default so that we can't put in two or more characters and shift focus onto the next span.

My problem is that after the first press focus doesn't shift, I need to press a button two times for it to work. What is the problem? I think it's my poor understanding of the event object but anyway I appreciate any help.

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle which demonstrate your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Use `keyup` instead of `keydown`. You want to check when a new digit has been added.
2. Use `$(this).html().length == max` to check when you have reached the max number of digits. Now you don't need to `substr`, just change focus to next element.

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaAU9/1/)** (Note: I changed span to inputs in example)

**UPDATE**

Here's the final code for future reference:

```
var max = 1;
$('form').find('input').keydown(function (e) {
    if ((e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 95 && e.which < 106)) {
        if ($(this).val().length < max) {
            return;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } else if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 9 && e.which != 46 && e.which != 37 && e.which != 38 && e.which != 39 && e.which != 40) e.preventDefault();
}).keyup(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length >= max) {
        if ($(this).is(':last-child'))
            $(this).parent().next().find('input:first-of-type').focus();
        else
            $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Due to keyup, inputs started accepting everything for some reason, but the focus indeed started to move right

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem with the last input, but still thanks, it did help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `keyup` instead of `keydown`.